# Is there anyway to set global hotkey for a mouse button?

Tags: c#, wpf, global-hotkey

I want to see if the user pressed for example mouse button left + ctrl key and call an event for it.

I've tried this and it didn't work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int VirtualKeyPressed);

while (true)
{
  if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x01)>0)
  {
     DoJob();
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

the problem with this code was it would capture it the first time but it wouldnt the second time (this was runing in a while loop)

Comment: Your code will only detect the left mouse click. You need to capture the ctrl key event passing 0x11 to GetAsyncKeyState function and combine the result with the if you wrote.

if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) != 0 && GetAsyncKeyState(0x11) != 0)
{
    DoJob();
}

Comment: Whenever you think about or see an infinite loop there must be alarm bells ringing. This is rarely a solution. It will block the thread, as the thread won't be able to do other work. Especially if this loop is executed on the main tread. Especially when the loop is waiting for a rare event like a key gesture.

Comment: Instead, you should always try to implement an event based (callback based) solution where the caller can interrupt the thread to notify about an event (e.g. key gesture), very much like system interrupts. If this isn't possible, then you would implement periodical polling using a timer. This allows the thread to execute other work while waiting for a particular event. In your case there are input events available. At OS level and at WPF level. You should prefer the WPF level input events. You can handle KEyDown events, routed commands to implenet global hot keys.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do what you are trying to accomplish with a `Window.InputBinding` and a `MouseBinding` attached to something like `Gesture="Ctrl+LeftClick"`.

If you take this approach, you can avoid using `user32.dll` and having to handle detecting the input in the code-behind.

Here is a simple example of binding to a command to an input for an entire `Window`:

```xml
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding CtrlLeftClickCommand}"
                      Gesture="Ctrl+LeftClick">
        </MouseBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

ViewModel

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand CtrlLeftClickCommand { get; set; } = new CtrlLeftClickCommand();
    // etc...
}
```

`ICommand` implementation, just in case you aren't familiar with this approach. If you wanted, you can also pass some sort of parameter via binding as well.

```cs
public class CtrlLeftClickCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        DoJob();
    }
    private void DoJob() => MessageBox.Show("Job Done!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you would define either a class level `KeyBinding`, `MouseBinding`, `CommandBinding` or a routed event class handler (e.g. for the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` routed event). If you register it with the application's visual root type `Window`, you have a global input gesture.

The following examples register an application wide gesture *Ctrl + LMousebutton* with starting a process (for demonstration purpose).

## Solution 1

You can define and handle a class level `CommandBinding` (recommended) or `InputBinding`.

Normally you would add the `CommandBinding` to the defining `UIElement.Commandings` collection to register the binding with the instance.
But because the command must be global, we must register it with a type instead of an instance. This is because an application can have multiple `Window` instances where each defines the root of its own visual tree. Now, instead of having to register a `CommandBinding` with every instance explicitly, we register the binding once for the `Window` type with the help of WPF's `CommandManager` helper class:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // Define as public so that the command can be used directly e.g., with a Button
  public static RoutedCommand StartProcessCommand { get; }

  public static MainWindow()
  {
    // Initialize a routed command with associated input gestures.
    // In this case the input gesture is a MouseGesture with a pressed modifier key (Ctrl).
    // Alternative track the CTRL key and create a KeyGesture instead.
    // Then, when executing the command, 
    // we can check if 'Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed' 
    var startProcessHotKey = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick, ModifierKeys.Control);
    MainWindow.StartProcessCommand = new RoutedCommand(nameof(MainWindow.StartProcessCommand), typeof(MainWindow));
    _ = MainWindow.StartProcessCommand.InputGestures.Add(startProcessHotKey);
  }
   
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create a CommandBinding to register the input event handlers
    var startProcessCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.StartProcessCommand, 
      ExecutedStartProcessCommand, 
      CanExecuteStartProcessCommand);

    // Register the command with every Window of this application.
    // The Window is always the root of a visual tree.
    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), startProcessCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteStartProcessCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true;

  private void ExecutedStartProcessCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // TODO::Execute StartProcessCommand
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
*Ctrl + LMouseButton* will execute the `MainWindow.StartProcessCommand` from every `Window` instance of the current application.
In addition, the `StartProcessCommand` can also be invoked explicitly e.g. by a `Button`:

```xml
<Window>
  <Button Command="{x:Static MainWindow.StartProcessCommand}" />
</Window>
```

## Solution 2

You can register a class handler for the mouse down event and check if the relevant keys are pressed. You do this with the help of WPF'S `EventManager` helper class.
The code is significantly shorter, but you lose functionality or flexibility, like global commanding and routing of the explicit command gesture that allows every element to handle it (without havig to explicitly check for the exact input gesture).

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
      typeof(Window), 
      PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent, 
      new RoutedEventHandler(OnGlobalPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp));
  }

  private void OnGlobalPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
      // TODO::Execute global input gesture
    }
  }
}
```